# What is the proper way to sync saved games on the PC version of FFIX?

Tags: steam, final-fantasy-series, final-fantasy-9

After having good FFIX memories on my PS1, I started playing FFIX on my PC (Steam) finalas well.

However, when I came to Lindblum and reinstalled Windows, downloaded Steam and FFIX again - my saved games were gone! And I used the Moogles to save my games.

What is the procedure I need to undertake in order for the saves to be synced?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Right click** on **game** in your Steam Library.
2. Select **Properties**.
3. Open **Updates** tab.
4. At the bottom you can enable **Steam Cloud** and see how much data is uploaded on Steam servers.

If it says `0 bytes`, there are no save games to sync from servers for this game.